# Tridion 2009 SP1, VirtualFolder not working

Tags: 2009, content-manager, search

We created new verity search folder using command:
mkvdk -create -locale uni -charmap utf8 -collection "\AMP3-DWW-002\newstagingtridionsearch\search"

And now search is resulting nothing in virtual folder.

While trying to synchronize any publication, a large number of files get created in /search/Documents folder and deleted automatically.

We have all the patches installed (as suggested by Tridion Support - 1.68438, 1.71326, 1.74923)

Please help us getting this resolved.

Also, new components do not reflect in virtual folder listing automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it is an old question, I thought to provide my observations and the resolution that worked for me.

We had found the solution by checking the verity search folder on impacted Tridion CMS and comparing it with the one where it was working fine.. There were a few files missing under /verity/common/styles directory. After putting these files, and restarting the Tridion search service, it worked fine.

This was found by using reflector on verity search dlls. :)

Comment: Is it for AMP - IONOS?

Comment: @Pankaj: yes it was realted to IONOS.

Comment: Old issue re-occurrence :P

Answer (score 5):

The search service is responsible for adding items to the search collection on save.  Maybe you can try removing your search index entirely and then following the LiveDocs instructions for creating it from scratch.  This will take many hours, so best to let it run overnight.

Here are a few quick checks to perform to help troubleshoot this issue:

- Is the SearchService working at all?
- Do you get any search results if searching for *?
- What about searching for a new item you just created?

Comment: Could you please provide me LiveDocs.

Comment: LiveDocs started in 2011.  See Chapter 5 in the SDL Tridion 2009 SP1 Maintenance Guide.  You may also want to look in the old Tridion forum for Verity related information.